# Scrape 3 tables and convert into workable df using beautifulsoup pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website that has three tables and convert it into either a df or csv that i can use for analysis. Here is the code i have and the issues i'm having at several steps. (warning: new to python)

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.happyhourspanish.com/learning-efficiently-start-with-the-250-most-common-spanish-words/',header=0)
for df in dfs:
    print(df) #loops all 3 tables
```

This code downloads all 3 tables containing 250 words into three columns -rank, spanish, english. When i try to save all 3 tables, the error says i can't save a list object into csv.

```
dfs.to_csv("Spanish_Key2.csv", index=False)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

When I save only one df, it only saves only the third of the 3 tables into csv.

```
df.to_csv("Spanish_Key.csv", index=False)
```

When i tried simply 'dfs', it displays three beautiful tables in a list format. Question here - how do i get this table format from a list into a dataframe with all 3 tables?

```
dfs
```

When i tried 'dfs[0]', it only puts the first table into a workable dataframe. How do i get the other two into this format?

```
dfs[0]
```

When i tried the following code, all 3 tables are now in one cell each, so the dataframe is only 3 cells.

```
import pandas as pd
spanish = pd.DataFrame(dfs)
spanish
```

Any suggestions on how to get all three tables into one dataframe OR all 3 tables into an csv with all 250 words in a separate cell, would be greatly appreciated.

If the solution is manipulate the excel, any suggestions on how to separate all the words into different cells? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want `pd.concat(dfs)`, which concatenates the three dataframes together row-wise.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it, seems to simple. I appreciate the time